# Renaming a class in Xcode causes conflict with subversion (Cornerstone)

Tags: xcode, refactoring, cornerstone

I'm refactoring a class in my Xcode project; after confirming to save the changes, I got an error saying "The request could not be performed because it was returned by Subversion as invalid"

All of the refactoring was done successfully, except for renaming the file itself. How can I rename the file/class in a "valid" way? The project is being subversioned by the Cornerstone application, do I need to rename the file from there?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error in 3 steps:

- Rename the file within the Cornerstone application
- In Xcode, Add the newly renamed file to the project
- The old file will appear red in the project navigator; delete the old file